# Making a read-only Object wrapper fool proof

Tags: javascript

I generate read-only wrappers for objects with the following code

```
function readOnlyObject(obj) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        defineProperty: function(obj, key, desc) {return;},

        set: function(obj, prop, val) {return;},

        deleteProperty: function(obj, prop) {return;},

        get: function(obj, prop, receiver) {
            if (obj[prop] instanceof Object) {
               return readOnlyObject(obj[prop]);
            }
            return Reflect.get(...arguments);
        }
    });
}
```

This is not about security from outside threats, but only to prevent me and my colleagues from shooting ourselves in the foot down the road.  Is there a Proxy function I forgot to overwrite, that might cause trouble when the proxy-object is passed around and written to?

Explanation: The object in question is passed to code that is runtime generated business logic -- written in a DSL by non-programmers that is translated to javascript; I have to protect the object against mistakes.  Passing in copies of the contained data as needed would be cumbersome, as everytime the businesslogic has a new requirement, the backend code would need to be touched and deployed.

Comment: Don't use `Proxy` in production code, especially not like this. They have significant performance overhead and are difficult to predict if you don't know _exactly_ what you're doing. Use TypeScript and / or a linter to avoid programmer errors without runtime overhead rather than silently preventing code from doing what was intended. _That's_ what will shoot people in the foot.

Answer (score -1):

sssstttttt......Theres this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

but you wont be able to even add a property to the frozen object.

-- opinion part --

Honestly, Im not sure what you're doing. You are holding yourselves from maturing. I've never done that, nor needed it, regardless of any factor. Because for me, whoever does this, made an equally terrible mistake as over-writing global object property.

Comment: I would need to deep-freeze the whole object at the get go; the deep-proxiing is done on demand, making it rather performant for now.